Optimizing an Objective Function While Minimizing an Argument?
I'd like to preface this by noting I'm not too familiar with optimization techniques, so something may or may not be off. Suppose I have some scalar function $f\left(x_1, x_2\right)$, where $x_1,x_2\geq 0$. My goal is to determine

the level set $f\left(x_1,x_2\right)=0$, which, from a priori knowledge, I know exists,
and, by extension, (and this is more important), the smallest $x_2$ on the level set. In other words, I hope to simultaneously minimize $x_2$.

From my limited expertise, I'd think this is a root-finding problem or, alternatively, a minimization problem (note that $f$, by default can output negative values but I believe I can simply consider $\left|f\right|$ to circumvent this). Naively using, e.g., Nelder-Mead in Python brings me close to what I want for the second bullet point above, but there is a noticeable discrepancy with the result I am expecting. Is there any way I can impose the additional constraint on $x_2$?

change your objective function to include minimizing the argument

@JobHunter69 could you comment further on this?

Rewrite this as a constrained minimization problem using Lagrange multipliers then numerically solve the system. The level curve can be found separately using your favorite numerical continuation technique

@whpowell96, thanks for the suggestion - again, though, if you could include additional details, maybe in a response, that'd be really helpful.

As a general optimization formulation, your problem can be written as,
\begin{align}
 \min_{x_1, x_2} \; &x_2 \\
\text{s.t.} \; & f(x_1, x_2) = 0 \\
& x_1, x_2 \geq 0
\end{align}
Most general optimization solvers should allow you to specify the objective ($\min x_2$) and the constraint ($f(x_1, x_2) = 0$). But a simpler approach may be to use bisection search:

Check if $f(x_1, 0) = 0$ has a non-negative solution in $x_1$. If so, you're done; $x_2 = 0 $ is the smallest value on your level set.
If not, find a high enough $b > 0$ such that $f(x_1, b) = 0$ has a non-negative solution in $x_1$.
Start with the interval $[a=0, b]$.
Check if there exists a solution for the mid-point in the level set, i.e. when $x_2 = \frac{a+b}{2}$. If yes, update $b = \frac{a+b}{2}$. If not, update $a = \frac{a+b}{2}$.
Repeat the above step until the gap between $a$ and $b$ is small enough for you (e.g $10^{-16}$). Basically, you are tightening the known bounds on the optimal value, $a \leq x_2^* \leq b$.


Interesting bissection method you built.
